# Using class level attributes of a subclass in a parent class function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-attributes

How can I change the respective class level attributes using the function of the base class without overloading the function?

```
class A:
    a = 0

    def addOne(self):
        print(A.a)      # prints 0
        A.a = A.a + 1
        print(A.a)      # it stores the value of a over all the child classes

class B(A):
    a = 0
    print(A.a)      # prints 0
    print(B.a)      # prints 0
    self.addOne()
    print(A.a)      # prints 1
    print(B.a)      # prints 0

Class C(A):
    a = 0
    print(A.a)      # prints 1
    print(C.a)      # prints 0
    self.addOne()
    print(A.a)      # prints 2
    print(C.a)      # prints 0
```

I want `B.a = 1` and `C.a = 1` after `self.addOne()`.

I don't want to use instance attributes as I will have to overload the addOne function for all the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function to get the class of `self`.

```
def addOne(self):
    cls = type(self)
    cls.a += 1
```

**Option 2:** Turn `addOne` into a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
@classmethod
def addOne(cls):
    cls.a += 1
```